# Using SmtpClient to send a file attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the `SmtpClient` class to send mail and also attach files. Everything seems to work fine, except that the filename in the email attachment says `filestest.docx` instead of `test.docx`. It is by default appending the folder name the file is located under. I would like to see only the actual file name.

```
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("I:/files/test.docx"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post you c# and HTML code. Probably you have hard-coded file name somewhere in your code.

Comment: if you move your test.docx to "I:/test.docx" does it still appears?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add a **ContentType** to your attachment.

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
contentType.Name = "test.docx";
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("I:/files/test.docx", contentType));
...
```

Comment: Hi Jac...adding content type fixed the issue. Thanks