# How to send saved pdf which exists within a folder using .net mvc 5

Tags: pdf, asp.net-mvc-5, email-attachments, rotativa

I am using Rotativa. MVC to generate a PDF from a view, so I can send an email with the PDF as an attachment. The following code does so:

```
var p = ControllerContext;
var h = new ViewAsPdf("Index") { FileName = "TestViewAsPdfHm.pdf" }; 
var hmm = h.BuildPdf(p); 
var memStream2 = new SysIO.MemoryStream(hmm);
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("From@gmail.com", "To@gmail.com");
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memStream2, "BuildPdfOption.pdf"));
```

My question is "How do I obtain a PDF file saved i.e. in my MVC application's Content/Pdf folder, from within in c# code, so I can attach it to an email in the same manner?"
I have tried many times with file,stream readers and with **HttpContext.Server.MapPath**, but without success. Using the **MapPath** option just had a textual document in the email that I couldn't open.

Comment: `Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/yourFileName.pdf")` ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680941/using-smtpclient-to-send-a-file-attachment

Comment: Yea the "Content Type" helped, thanks. Just add the code:
ContentType myType = new ContentType { MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, Name = "MyFileName" }; 
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment ("fileName", myType));